# Uploading to private S3 bucket from SpringBoot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3

What's a good way to only allow access to a bucket by a specific web app? I need the app to be able to access them by url, but I don't want anyone not using it to be able to use the bucket object url to view it in a browser.

I tried a different bucket policy that would only allowed certain ip's but I couldn't get it formatted properly.

Currently there is nothing blocked in the "Block public access (bucket settings)" section.

Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::nameofthebucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

CORS Policy

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://www.example1.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Comment: So what exactly do you want to accomplish ?

Comment: My SpringApp uses Put, Get, and Delete methods to upload, download, and get files from the s3 bucket so I need this access. And then in the front end I am using wavesurfer.js to read the file url from a hidden text field on the jsp page. This hidden url value is visible from the inspect window of the browser, so I need the app to be able to read it but also deny access to anyone trying to access the url directly in the broswer.